# How to select webelement from dropdown menu using webdriver

Tags: java, html, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select a webelement from a dropdown but not able to do so. 
The webelement which i am trying to select from the drop down is 
**Edit/ViewResume**

---

### 1st Try

In my first attempt i tried to select the webelement by using Action and Select class methods. Here to select the element from the dropdown i tried selectByValue(value), selectByIndex(1) and selectByVisibleText(text) but none of them worked and i got **org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "a"** this exception.

```
  Webelement wb = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ns_menu_item_wrap ns_lt active']/a"));
  Actions mouse = new Actions(driver);
  mouse.moveToElement(wb).perform();
  Select sel = new Select(wb);
  sel.selectByIndex(1);
```

---

### 2nd Try

Here i tried to select the element by using Action class build(), click() and perform() methods but nothing happened i.e, i am still not able to select the webelement from the dropdown. For this code i am not getting any exception.

```
  Webelement wb = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ns_menu_item_wrap ns_lt active']/a"));
  Actions mouse = new Actions(driver);
  mouse.moveToElement(wb).click();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10 , TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  wb=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'http://my.monsterindia.com/view_resume.html?mode=edit')]"));
  mouse.moveToElement(wb).click();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10 , TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  mouse.build();
  Thread.sleep(4000);
  mouse.perform();
```

---

### HTML Snippet of dropdown option

```
<div class="ns_menu_item_wrap ns_lt active">
<a class="ns_menu_item" href="http://my.monsterindia.com/my_monster.html">My Monster</a>
<div class="ns_dropdown" style="display: none; left: -2px;">
<div class="ns_dropdown_inner">
<div class="ns_dd_link_wrap">
<a class="ns_dd_link" href="http://my.monsterindia.com/view_resume.html?mode=edit">Edit/View Resume</a>
<a class="ns_dd_link" href="http://my.monsterindia.com/applications.html">My Applications</a>
<a class="ns_dd_link" href="http://my.monsterindia.com/manageagents.html">Job Agent</a>
<a class="ns_dd_link" href="http://my.monsterindia.com/confidentiality.html">Privacy Plus</a>
<a class="ns_dd_link" href="http://my.monsterindia.com/newsletter.html">Subscriptions</a>
</div>
<div class="ns_dd_othertxt">
<div class="ns_clr"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i was not able to paste  the code in comment thats why putting it as an answer-
In this code i am getting output for System.out.println("2"); as 2 but not getting any output for System.out.println("3");
Am i doing a mistake in the logic?

```
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10 , TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  wb = driver.findElement(By.linkText("My Monster"));
  Actions mouse = new Actions(driver);
  mouse.moveToElement(wb).click();
  System.out.println("2");
  WebElement wb1 = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Edit/View Resume"));
  mouse.moveToElement(wb1).click();
  mouse.build();
  mouse.perform();
  System.out.println("3");
```

Comment: when you are saying `mouse` to `moveToElement`, you need to make it `build` and `perform` when multiple actions involved. Here you missed out this for first `moveToElement`

Comment: @nitin chawda I added mouse.build(); and mouse.perform(); for the first moveToElement but still  System.out.println("3"); is not getting printed

Answer (score 0):

There is no HTML `select` item in the markup you provided. Check [here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) for details. You have only links there. So why don't you just click on that link. That would be something like:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Job Agent")).click();
```

Or whichever that is you need to click.

Comment: When i did the code change in try1 as per your suggetion i recived org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "a"  exception.

Comment: And when i did the same in try2 notjing happened i.e, not getting results nor any exception

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd try looks a bit strange, because in your action you call `mouse.moveToElement(wb)` and then assign another element to `wb` before performing that action. I would like to try the following:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10 , TimeUnit.SECONDS); // It is enough to call this once
Webelement wb = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ns_menu_item_wrap ns_lt active']/a"));
Actions mouse = new Actions(driver);
mouse.moveToElement(wb).click();
Webelement wb2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'http://my.monsterindia.com/view_resume.html?mode=edit')]"));
mouse.moveToElement(wb2).click();
mouse.build(); // You don't need the sleep after this before calling perform()
mouse.perform();
```

But like ErkiM. suggested, I don't see why a simple

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'http://my.monsterindia.com/view_resume.html?mode=edit')]"));
```

couldn't work.

Comment: Sir I realised my mistake and did exactly same as you suggested but still it is not clicking on the webelement and not giving any exception

Comment: Sir i was not able to put my code as comment thats why i put it as an answer. Please check it once